# Illustrator: Saving CMYK document to PDF, color change to RGB

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf, color-spaces

I am having a strange problem.

I double-checked, and my document is set to CMYK, and I am using a specific ICC profile as well. I have some other documents where I am doing the same.

Oddly, I thought all of these documents were the same color-settings wise, but when I used Bridge to review the color spaces of my saved out PDF documents, I had everything from CMYK, to RGB, to unspecified...

Now, the printer said that I don't need to include the ICC profile, so if that part doesn't show up, that would be okay. But I do expect the document to at least say that it is CMYK. I am using typical PDF X3 standards. Does anyone have any ideas of what might cause this? Thanks in advance for your suggestions!

Comment: Have you *verified* files have changed.. or are you merely relying on what Bridge is reporting? It could very well be Bridge displaying incorrect information.

Comment: I am confused about how to properly determine what the files are... Also, why would Bridge report the wrong metadata? - It seems to me that Acrobat is showing CYMK, but nothing looks definitive. It's all like "preferred profile" instead of saying what the document actually is. Also Brigde is reading similiar files differently.... CYMK, RGB, untagged - it seems like something is different about the files, or it shouldn't be doing this. It is possible that some of my links were still in RGB, but I was converting the illustrator files themselves thinking this would eradicate the problem.

Comment: But I made sure that those were converted to CYMK and I resaved the document giving me issue... I even tried to converting it to the Web Swop 2 profile on save out... and even then Bridge is reading it as RGB... I am really scratching my head over this.

Comment: I wouldn't care with Bridge reports (I, personally think Bridge is a waste of HDD space). You should be able to determine everything about color using Acrobat's tools. Bridge is a *file browser* and not a production tool.

Comment: Okay, but how do I find this information in Acrobat? I can't seem to find this "Advanced" tab everyone keeps talking about, and the preflight windows are all about making conversions, not showing the actual status of the document. There is an info to the left, but if that is true, then my documents are largely "untagged", so neither specified to be RGB or CYMK... though it seems my "preferred profile" is still the ICC profile I specified... I just find it weird that this would be the case, and yet my document is not showing up in CYMK. I also don't know how to change it.

Comment: I mean, I even tried converting to an ICC profile on save out.... and that didn't seem to work.

Comment: I double-checked the "i" (info panel) in Adobe Acrobat, and it seems that this is completely blank for several of my documents, which were saved out similarly to the ones who do show information.... So I find this really odd. The "RGB" one is also showing up blank.

Comment: A pdf file can not essentially be simply a cmyk or rgb document since its a page description language. It can simply be both at the same time or it can simply be neither. Individual elements of a pdf file simply are either described as rgb, cmyk, spot or black color. So any system that reports it as either or is simply lying. What you want to do is check that all elements are defined in cmyk. Since x-3 does not forbid usage of RGB elements then the only way to verify is check each subelement. But then the question is why use x-3 in the firstplace.